# Google+ API not responding when login in

Tags: haskell, google-api, yesod

I am working on a website, and to save me the trouble of a private database I decided to use the Google API to authenticate users. I followed [this](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/authentication-and-authorization) guide. I copied the code and yet when I run it and try to log in, I get the google screen where I choose the account to log in with. I choose my account and then it keeps on loading for a lot of time (I left it for half an hour with no change). In addition, The application starts eating my ram (it uses everything it can from my 16GB).

I am not sure where it went wrong. Maybe someone encountered this thing before?

Cheers

Edit:
Here is the code I use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}

module Main where

import Data.Default (def)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Network.HTTP.Client.Conduit (Manager, newManager)
import Yesod
import Yesod.Auth
import Yesod.Auth.BrowserId
import Yesod.Auth.GoogleEmail2

clientId :: Text
clientId = "" --Removed it for public view

clientSecret :: Text
clientSecret = "" --Removed it for public view

data App = App
    { httpManager :: Manager
    }

mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
/auth AuthR Auth getAuth
|]

instance Yesod App where
    approot = ApprootStatic "http://localhost:3000"

instance YesodAuth App where
    type AuthId App = Text

    loginDest _ = HomeR
    logoutDest _ = HomeR

    authPlugins _ =
        [ authGoogleEmail clientId clientSecret
        ]

    authHttpManager = httpManager

    maybeAuthId = lookupSession "_ID"

instance RenderMessage App FormMessage where
    renderMessage _ _ = defaultFormMessage

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
  maid <- maybeAuthId
  defaultLayout
      [whamlet|
          <p>Your current auth ID: #{show maid}
          $maybe _ <- maid
              <p>
                  <a href=@{AuthR LogoutR}>Logout
          $nothing
              <p>
                  <a href=@{AuthR LoginR}>Go to the login page
      |]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    man <- newManager
    warp 3000 $ App man
```

And here is snippet from the cabal file (I use stack to build the executable):

```
executable App-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , yesod
                     , yesod-auth
                     , text
                     , http-conduit
                     , data-default
                     , OWTeamQueue
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Comment: Hi. Questions on stackoverflow are intended to be self-contained (it should still make sense even if every single link in your question were invalid). Please post a _small_ code snippet that reproduces the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I did not implement the `getAuthId` function in the instance for `YesodAuth App`. I am not sure why this did not appear as an error/warning when I built it with stack.